# Angular 8 - change mat-form-field outline color dynamically

Tags: css, angular

I am new to Angular using Angular 8 - I want to change the mat-form-field outline color from black to grey when the control is set to read-only (similar to when I field is disabled) - fields are set to read-only dynamically - I have found snippets of code that partially do what I need but nothing that works entirely

The following snippet will set the background color for read-only controls however I want to set the outline color:

```
input[readonly], input:read-only {background-color: red!important;}
```

The following snippet will set the outline color like I would like however it sets for all controls:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline (color: red!important;}
```

I already have attributes set for .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline in my style sheet that sets the default look and field for all controls so I either need to have an additional entry for .mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-outline that is combined with the read-only entry or I need to modify the existing entry so that is takes into account fields that are read-only

please excuse any misuse of terminology